# (SWIFT) Sprite not giving me the correct zRotation value after being added

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit, angle, skspritenode

**Details of program:** by looking at this picture(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOZ53.png), what I'm trying to do is have the spaceship circle the planet. I achieved this by making a line node and changes its anchor point to the top and then position it to the centre of the planet which then upon impact of the spaceship and planet, the line is angled towards the ship in which then the ship is removed from the view and added to the line node as a child and together they rotate around the planet, as the ship rotates around the the planet, the ship it self also rotates on the spot  (hopefully that makes sense)

**Problem:** the problem is im not getting the correct zRotation value of the ship. Right now I got the code to draw another ship at the location where it was tapped and set the zRotation of that image to the zRotation of the ship but i keep getting different angles. (refer to picture). Is this because I have ship added to line node as a child? Im running a rotating animation on both the line and the ship. In the picture, the line is rotating around the planet counter clockwise dragging the ship along with it and the ship itself is also rotating counter clockwise on the spot. In the picture the left ship; the one that's touching the line is the one thats rotating, the ship on the right is just drawn to angle of the rotating ship but by looking at the picture you can see the angle of the ship is pretty opposite of the one on the left. Why is this so? what I noticed is that when the ship is at the bottom half of the planet, the angles are fine but when it comes to the top half, the angles are kinda opposite(refer to picture)

**Picture**

[image]

**Console Log:**

**I'm Touched -**
*ship angle in degrees*: 83.6418545381942
*PLAYER POSITION X:* 100.0 *Y*: 100.0 
*PLAYER ZROTATION:* 1.45982575416565

**WE'RE TOUCHING -**
*PLANET POSITION* X*: 120.0 *Y*: 230.000015258789
*PLAYER-SHIP POSITION X*: 107.998710632324 *Y*: 171.783294677734 
*ANGLE OF LINE* RADIANS*: -1.77409685090117 *DEGRESS*: -101.648262004087 
*PLAYER-SHIP ROTATION*: 1.57079637050629

**I'm Touched** -
*ship angle in degrees*: 314.660859137531 
*TEMP POS X*: 136.535125732422 *Y*: 287.094879150391 
*TEMP ZROTATION*: 5.491868019104
*PLAYER POSITION X*: 136.535125732422 *Y*: 287.094879150391 
*PLAYER ZROTATION:* 5.491868019104

**Collision Code:**

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == planetGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == planetGroup {


         print(" WE'RE TOUCHING ")

        moving = true
        touching = true

        let degrees = 45.0
        let radians = degrees * M_PI / 180.0

        //rotate Line
        var rotateLine = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(radians), duration: 0.5)
        var repeatLine = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateLine)

        //rotates Ship
        var rotateShip = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(radians), duration: 0.4)
        var repeatShip = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateShip)



        playerShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)


        planetNode = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode


        planetX = planetNode.position.x
        planetY = planetNode.position.y

        playerX = playerShip.position.x
        playerY = playerShip.position.y


        var angleOfAnchor = AngleBetweenPoints(planetNode.position, endPoint: playerShip.position)
        var three60 = 360 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
        var nintey = 90 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
        var inDegree = angleOfAnchor * 180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI)

        var shipPlanetDistance = SDistanceBetweenPoints(planetNode.position, p2: playerShip.position)


        line = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: 2, height: planetNode.size.height))
        line.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        line.position = CGPoint(x: planetX, y: planetY)

        line.zRotation = -(three60 - nintey - angleOfAnchor)

        self.addChild(line)
        tempShip = playerShip
        playerShip.removeFromParent()
        line.runAction(repeatLine, withKey: "rotateLine")


        //playerShip.position = CGPoint(x: playerX, y: playerY)
        line.addChild(playerShip)
        playerShip.zRotation = (90 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0)

        playerShip.runAction(repeatShip, withKey: "rotateShip")

        print("*PLANET POSITION* X: \(planetX) Y: \(planetY)  \r *PLAYER-SHIP POSITION* X: \(playerX) Y: \(playerY) \r *ANGLE OF LINE* RADIANS: \(angleOfAnchor) DEGRESS: \(inDegree) *PLAYER-SHIP ROTATION: \(playerShip.zRotation)")
    }

}
```

**Screen Touch Code:**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    print(" I'm Touched ")

    var radians:CGFloat = playerShip.zRotation
    var degrees = radians * 180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI)
    var dx = cos(radians)
    var dy = sin(radians)
    print(" ship angle in degrees: \(degrees) ")

    var tempAngle = playerShip.zRotation

    var shipPosition = convertPoint(playerShip.position, fromNode: line)

    playerX = shipPosition.x
    playerY = shipPosition.y



    if startMove == true {

        playerShip.removeActionForKey("rotateShip")

        playerShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 100*dx, dy: 100*dy)// speed of direction
        startMove = false

    }

    if moving == true{

        //playerShip.removeActionForKey("rotateShip")

        //playerShip.removeFromParent()
        //self.addChild(playerShip)


        var radians:CGFloat = playerShip.zRotation
        var degrees = radians * 180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI)
        var dx = cos(radians)
        var dy = sin(radians)
        print(" ship angle in degrees: \(degrees) ")



        //playerShip.zRotation = tempShip.zRotation
        //playerShip.position = CGPoint(x: playerX, y: playerY)
        //playerShip.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 100*dx, dy: 100*dy)// speed of direction


        // this is the ship that gets drawn
        var temp = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "img/ship/2.png")
        temp.position = CGPoint(x: playerX, y: playerY)
        temp.zRotation  = playerShip.zRotation
        self.addChild(temp)



        //moving = false
        print("*TEMP POS* X: \(temp.position.x) Y: \(temp.position.y) *TEMP ZROTATION*: \(temp.zRotation)")



    }

    print("*PLAYER POSITION* X: \(playerX) Y: \(playerY) *PLAYER ZROTATION: \(playerShip.zRotation)")


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, I added the line.zrotation with the playerShip.zrotation and it ended up working perfectly